# How do I add additional bones to a previously made rig and mesh so that I can animate a 3d model's hair?

Tags: animation

I made a character and it has been rigged. Her hair doesn't move so I tried adding bones to it and parenting it in edit mode to both the main head  bone and creating a new vertex group for the hair mesh. I am trying to animate the character's hair when she walks. However, nothing I've tried so far has worked. Any ideas? Also if by some miracle I get this to work, must I animate the hair for each one of my animations?

Comment: why didn't it work? Also, maybe show some pictures? I guess the solution depends on the style, topology, etc... If it's not a realistic character, the Wiggles Bones addon may help

Comment: The bone at the end of the pony tail moves due to the wiggle addon, but the hair mesh and the rest of the bones attached do not move at all. I created the bones by moving a new bone, not originally part of the rig, and placing it at the base of the ponytail. From there, I extruded the bone so that it aligns with the ponytail. I then parented the bone to the main head bone and created a new vertex group so the hair mesh would be attached to the ponytail bones. I'll provide visuals a later today. It should be noted that her ponytail rests on her shoulder.

Comment: Here is a video: https://youtu.be/Wbz21wpydrI